# How to order database results in a particular order?

Tags: php, sql, database, dropdown

I want the results to be ordered based on what the user selects.

code:

```
<?php
include('connectdb.php');
echo "<h1>All the Events </h1>
<table cellspacing='0'  cellpadding='5'>
<tr><th>Event Category</th> <th >Event Name</th><th >Time</th> <th >Description</th></th>
  <select>
    <option name='date' value='dateorder'>Date</option>
    <option name='name' value='name'>A-Z</option>


  </select> "
 ?>
```

For now there's two options; user can sort by date or name.....

In the same file I have this code:

```
<?php
try{
// Run a SQL query
  $sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY ";
...
```

I want the result to be ordered based on what the users select from the dropdown list. How do I get the value from the dopdown list and use it in this SQL query??

Comment: `<option>` doesn't have a `name` attribute, that should be in your `<select>`. Get the value of your `<select>` and order by that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your custom wrapper on table I would recommend to use the wheel instead of re-inventing it.

Use [datatables](https://datatables.net/)

- It has server side pagination
- It has client side pagination
- It has export feature
- It has responsiveness
- **It has sorting feature (exactly like you need)**
- It has search feature

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Made things easier